# UWP Content Dialog - Updating fields Dynamically

Tags: c#, uwp, dialog

I have a content dialog box and I have textbox on it that I want to use to give users feedback:

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=ContentDialog, Path=errMsg, Mode=OneWay}" Width="300" />
```

In my code behind I have the following code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "errMsg", typeof(string), typeof(ContentDialog), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));





public string errMsg
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue( TextProperty, value); }
    }
```

and in order to populate the errMsg I use the following code:

```
if (hiveIDTxt.Text == null | hiveIDTxt.Text=="")
            {
                errMsg = "The Hive ID Cannot be Empty";
            }
```

I've stepped through the code and everything happens that should EXCEPT nothing happens onscreen.

can anyone tell me what I'mm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Paul.

Comment: For one thing, your `DependencyProperty` needs to be named `errMsgProperty` by convention. For another thing, `ContentDialog` is not the owner of the DP (you are). You should read the [DP overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview) topic.

Comment: thanks Peter. I spent some time looking at this and decided to revert to just setting a text property of the textblock instead.